# Reading local JSON file with SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

and i wanted to read my "data.json" that is located in "Supporting Files" Folder.
But i am confused, because a lot of the Tutorials are either swift 1.0 or don't show how it is done with a local file.

Can somebody help me ?

This is how far i have come :

```
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("data", ofType: "json") {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfMappedFile: path) {
            let json = JSON(data: data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil)
            println("jsonData:\(json)")
        }
    }
```

i also get a warning that "contentsOfMappedFile" is deprecated.

i tried for 20mins, couldn't get it to work :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `init(contentsOfMappedFile:)` is deprecated in iOS8.

So you should change this

```
data = NSData(contentsOfMappedFile: path)
```

to

```
data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)
```